Find the equation of the closure of a curve in the projective space
Let k be an algebrically closed field and consider $C \subset \mathbb{A}^2(k)$, the curve of equation $f(X,Y)=0$ with $f(X,Y)=X(X-1)(X+1)-Y^2$.
We want to find the equation of its closure in $\overline{C} \subset \mathbb{P} ^2 (k)$. 
I know that its image (if we include $\mathbb{A}^2(k)$ in $\mathbb{P} ^2 (k)$ the canonical way) is defined has the zero locus of the homogenization of f which is $f^h(X,Y,Z)=X^3-XZ^2-Y^2Z$ but I don't know how to get from this to the closure.
Thank you in advance

What do you mean by "its image ... is defined has the zero locus of the homogenization"? The closure of $C$ is the zero locus of the homogenization.

@ronno Actually, that is the part I did not understood/knew, for me it was not clear that the zero locus of the homogenized polynomial was the closure of C. I thought this zero locus was the image of C by the canonical from the affine space to the projective one, so it was clearly included in the closure but not necessarily equal to the said closure.

The way you embed $\mathbb{A}^2\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ is by identifying $\mathbb{A}^2$ with $D_+(Z).$ So it suffices to show that $V(X(X-1)(X+1)-Y^2)=D_+(Z)\cap V_{+}(X^3-XZ^2-Y^2Z)$ is dense in $V_{+}(X^3-XZ^2-Y^2Z).$ This is true as $V_+(X^3-XZ^2-Y^2Z)$ is irreducible.
